# how does this switch block executes?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void show(int errorCause)
{
    switch(errorCause)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cout<<"in 1\n";
            break;
        }

        case 2: break;

        case 3:
        {
            cout<<"in 3\n";
            break;

            case 4: 
            {
                cout<<"in 4\n";
                case 5: cout<<"in 5\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default: 
        {
            cout<<"in deafult\n";
            break;
       }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    show(5);
    return 0;
}
```

I used this sample of code and I could not figure out its flow.According to me it should match the default condition as the errorCause does not match anything,but its output is:

```
in 5
```

I don't understand why it is not going to default condition?

Here is my build environment details:

compiler:
g++ version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

System:
Ubuntu 14.04(64-bit)

Comment: Format your code please... I, if imagined as compiler, would have refused to read and parse this code, firsthand.

Comment: Debugger is perfect, when trying to understand code flow - you can just step through a program step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't write code like that. <g>

Second, the reason that it gets to `case 5:` is simply that there's a `case 5:` inside the switch statement. It doesn't matter that it's nested inside two levels of curly braces; it's just a label for the code to jump to. It doesn't have to be at the outer level of the switch statement.

Answer (score 4):

You pass 5, why should the switch statement not go into 'case 5'?

To make it clear: Remove all these curly braces inside the switch-block, none of them is necessary. The re-align and format the code, then it should be clear.

Comment: The thing is that if the code was formatted properly, you would see what is causing the OP confusion - some of the `case` statements are inside different levels of braces. But that it is actually allowed.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, and I know that the curly braces don't matter for reaching the case statement, so, to make it simple for somebody that is a beginner and does *not* know all this stuff: remove the curly braces.

Comment: Well, yes, if you remove the curly braces, the question goes away. But that doesn't explain why the code with the curly braces is okay.

Answer (score 3):

`case`/`default` labels for a `switch` statement may appear anywhere within that `switch` statement, except within a nested `switch` statement.

A famous example of this usage is [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) for unrolling loops:

```
void copy(unsigned char *to, const unsigned char *from, size_t count)
{
    size_t n;

    if (!count)
        return;

    n = (count + 7) / 8;
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0:
        do {
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 1:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 2:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 3:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 4:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 5:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 6:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 7:
            *to++ = *from++;
    case 1:
        } while (--n > 0);
    }
}
```

(adapted from the original).

At first glance, that doesn't make any sense (and it is somewhat redundant if you allow the compiler to unroll loops for you), but it illustrates that `case` labels can be placed more or less where you like within the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's because actually the `switch` statement evaluation is "relaxed", so the braces do not matter there. Only `case` matters, but you can jump right into the middle of a scope by the `case` (or even to the middle of a loop, see [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device)).

Answer (score 0):

because the value you passed is 5 , which exactly matches with the switch case parameter.

case 5: cout<<"in 5\n";
         break;

if you want to get the default statement then modify the main function as shown below :

```
  int main()
{
  show(6);
  return 0;
}
```

hope this helps.